# Adding Past Due Assignments to Dashboard in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to add a section on my dashboard to quickly visualize past due assignments in Google Sheets. I want to pull from the "Key Results" tab to the dashboard tab and display the name of the task that's past due based on the "Objective" that it falls under.

I started with this formula =FILTER(KeyResultData!A1:G113, KeyResultData!G1:G113<TODAY()), but it gave me an error message (Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in G26.). I am not sure how to add in additonal commands to condition on objective (Column B) and to display the name of the assignment name (Column C).

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform).